# Auto Detect Port that is connected by GSM Modem in C#

Tags: c#, port, gsm, modem

How to autodetect or autoconnect the port that is connected by GSM Modem.  Assuming that I already have the variables. What I want to do is that I don't want to set the **portName** that it will automatically get the **portName**. Please help!!! Thanks in advance!

```
using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;
using GsmComm.PduConverter.SmartMessaging;
using GsmComm.Interfaces;
using GsmComm.Server;

public void SetData(string portName, int baudRate, int timeout)
{
    this.portName = portName;
    this.baudRate = baudRate;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}

public void GetData(out string portName, out int baudRate, out int timeout)
{
    portName = this.portName;
    baudRate = this.baudRate;
    timeout = this.timeout;
}

private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    portName = "COM43";
    baudRate = 9600;
    timeout = 300;
    comm = new GsmCommMain(portName, baudRate, timeout);
    comm.Open();
}
```

Comment: Does it connects by Serial Port?

Comment: This question is way too light on details. We need to know exactly what you are trying to achieve in order to help you, so please provide all the relevant code (but not more than that) you have written to do what you want so far.

Comment: @tweelt Yes, It connects with a serial port.

Comment: @hlovdal Here is my code...

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle through all the COM ports in the system (their list is easily get programmatically) and send command receiving GSM modem version or model (as i remember yo can do it via GsmComm library).